# At modules window i can see loaded dll apear twice with same path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5

Can you tell me please what is the reason , is it loaded twice from same location

Comment: Which dll? In which application? Is it causing problems? What do you want to be solved?

Comment: @user##, at least post the relevant lines from the Output or Modules Window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always thought this was something to do with having both native and managed code in the same dll / exe. I see the same thing in my apps where the native C++ modules load a managed licence handler module.