# One of the Dll files is listed twice in the modules window

Tags: c#, dll

When debugging my app in VS2010, I found that one of the dll's is listed twice.
The "Path" of each are from different locations but the symbol file is the same.
The Dll under question had to be on a specific location on my or the client's PC, but
now I can only run my app if it is in the same folder as the app. Is there a way that
I can manually see which dll files are linked to the application and maybe edit it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067200/at-modules-window-i-can-see-loaded-dll-apear-twice-with-same-path

Comment: After further testing I found out that the referenced dll must me located in BOTH the GAC_MSIL folder AND in the same folder as the application for the application to run.